# Is executing something asynchronously the same as pushing it to the back of the call stack?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

> "When there's nothing to do, check the queue. But only check the queue
>   when there's nothing left to do."

~ Javascript (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMfg0xGjcOI)

So from what I understand, it basically means that you're delaying execution. Something like

```
SomeAsynchronousFunction();
SomeRegularFunction();
SomeOtherRegularFunction();
```

just means that you're essentially rearranging the tasks to

```
SomeRegularFunction();
SomeOtherRegularFunction();
SomeAsynchronousFunction();
```

in terms of how the bodies of the three functions are executed. Except that, if your browser/hardware supports parallel computing, and if the body of `SomeAsynchronousFunction` does not have any dependency on the other two functions, that it will be executed in parallel with the other two functions. Is that right? Or am I totally confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. But usually there will be some parts of `SomeAsynchronousFunction` that are synchronous, and those will be executed immediately -- it's only the completion of the function that's async. For instance, it might perform an AJAX call, so it first creates the XHR object, collects the parameters into a `FormData` object, and calls `xhr.send()` immediately; the asynchronous part is the execution of the `onreadystatechange` callback function, which happens when the server responds and the event processing loop has nothing else to do. So the actual order of execution is like this:

```
synchronous parts of SomeAsynchronousFunction();
SomeRegularFunction();
SomeOtherRegularFunction();
callback function from SomeAsynchronousFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on a single thread, is non-blocking and uses what's called an event loop so your functions run in the original order, but the asynchronous calls, when they return add another message to the event loop and get executed when all other preceeding messages in the event loop are processed. For more info,  I recommend reading this article from the Mozilla Developer Network, [Concurrency model and Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: @Barmar, looks like my Android app didn't refresh with your answer before I answered ;)